# embedded image data

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox3.6

I've noticed that in recent versions of Firefox, some images are displayed even when I disable images (e.g., Google News). Apparently this is due to images being embedded in the code using the "data:image" specification. Does anyone know of a way to disable these images from being displayed?

The reason I'm posting this here rather than on the Mozilla forums is because I suspect the resolution will be along the lines of creating a script (extension) that modifies the page's code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Install the 'Web Developer Toolbar' extension if you don't have it.
- Go to Images > Disable Images > [appropriate choice].
- Then go to Options > Persist Features

Comment: That's truly a great extension. But it didn't solve my problem! Google News still displays the embedded images.